# Team Foundation Service won't let me add members

Tags: visual-studio-2012, azure-devops

I have successfully set up a Team Foundation Service account and have been using it with Visual Studio 2012 for source code control, no problems.  Note this is the online service, not the old TFS product. I now want to add another Live ID account so they can write and track bugs.  Using the Manage Members link I have tried two different Live ID accounts as well as their name but it always says they are not a known user.  I know the Live ID accounts are correct.  Do I have to invite them or add them some other way first?  All of the examples show it "just working".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you adding them via the web interface?  You should be able to do this by clicking the cog icon in the *yourproject*.visualstudio.com site.  This launches the admin site, you can go into a collection, or add from the Security tab.  It really depends on where you want to add them (if they only need access to specific projects/collections it's done at that level), you can add a new user from the Overview or Security tabs by entering their Live ID/email address.

Comment: Wow, not sure why this was so obtuse.  Thank you for pointing out the cog...duh.  But then the only way to add someone was to make my way to the project security tab, get to Users and get to the Add... button.  Then the way the dialog behaved it looked like it couldn't find the user because they had a red X next to their name, which I now realize means Delete.  Just typing their address and Save worked.  Thank you!  Brian